# Mesa EGL not working, not even initializing

Tags: ubuntu, opengl

Nearly a week now, and I can't figure out what's wrong! Any pointers would be appreciated (pun intended)!

Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64
Mesa-8.0.4

> ./configure --enable-64-bit --enable-pic -enable-opengl --enable-gles2 --enable-xorg --enable-egl --enable-glu --with-x

(Also tried with the apt-get package of Mesa)

```
ls /usr/local/lib | grep EGL  
libEGL.so@  
libEGL.so.1@  
libEGL.so.1.0*
```

[When running the simple tutorial code](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/eglIntro.html)

```
display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);  
EGLBoolean err = eglInitialize(display, NULL, NULL);
```

initialize fails and further functions return `EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED`.

Comment: [apt-get install libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxcb-dri2-0-dev](http://old.nabble.com/egl_dri2%3A-Checking-for-xcb-dri2.h-and-xcb-xfixes.h-p29151960.html) helps building the Mesa.

Answer (score 2):

Under an X desktop, you cannot use `EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY`. You must pass to `eglGetDisplay()` a pointer to a valid Xlib `Display`. For example:

```
EGLBoolean ok;

Display *xlib_dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
if (!xlib_dpy)
  return;

EGLDisplay egl_dpy = eglGetDisplay(xlib_dpy);
if (!egl_dpy)
  return;

int major;
int minor;
ok = eglInitialize(egl_dpy, &major, &minor);
if (!ok)
  return;

if (10 * major + minor != 14) {
  /* EGL is too old; */
  return;
}
```